# placing float at the end of second column

Tags: floats, two-column, article

I am writing a very simple poster class. There will be some text in two columns and in the right column should be a text box/some floats at the end. Placing them at the bottom is not a problem, **but** how to place the floats always in the right column?

This is how it should look like:

[image: float in right column due to more text]

But now with less text:

[image: float in left column with little text]

Using `\newpage` might push it to a second page if the text is longer than one column.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{foo}{!b}{foo}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[2] % change to 5 to push the foo-box to the second column

\begin{foo}
        here will be some sort of text box
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more difficult question is what to do if there is more text afterward.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{foo}{b}{foo}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{foop}{\if@firstcolumn\newpage\leavevmode\fi
\foo}{\endfoo}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\blindtext[2] % change to 5 to push the foo-box to the second column

\begin{foop}[!b]% will be handled by \foo
        here will be some sort of text box
\end{foop}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works very well. I've seen `\if@firstcolumn` before but could not get it to work. There should not be any text afterwards, not a relevant use case.